# Statistics problem about Possibility principle

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, random

I have a question about the following problem from the first edition of Introduction to Probability by Joseph K. Blitzstein and Jessica Hwang. This is problem 68 from Chapter 4.

> Each of 111 people names his or her 5 favorite movies out of a list of
> 11 movies.
>
> Show that there are 2 movies such that at least 21 of the people name
> both of these movies as favorites.

The possibility principle states that

> The possibility principle: Let A be the event that a randomly chosen
> object in a collection has a certain property. If P(A) > 0, then there
> exists an object with the property.

Is it enough to state that the probability of two specific movies being chosen by at least 21 people is ${111\choose 21}{(2/11)}^{21} $ (where 2/11 is the probability of the two movies being chosen by a specific person) and therefore since this probability is greater than 0 then by the possibility principle there exist two  movies that are chosen by at least 21 people? But then it could also be said that there are 5 movies that are chosen by all 111 people.

Comment: Your statement refers to "both of these movies".  You haven't defined which movies.

Comment: That refers to any group of two movies - the problems asks to show that there exist at least one group of two movies that are chosen by at least 21 people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given problem describes a procedure -- which is *not* supposed to be random -- that produces a list of $111$ (not necessarily distinct) size-$5$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,11\}.$ Let's denote such a list as $s=[s_1,\ldots,s_{111}],$ and, for any two numbers $(a,b)$, define
$$X(a,b,s):=\text{number of elements in list $s$ that contain both $a$ and $b$}.$$ We're asked to prove the following:
$$\forall s\,\exists(a,b):X(a,b,s)\gt 20\tag{*}$$
where the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ abbreviate "for all" and "there exists", respectively.

Now we consider how to make $X$ a random variable to give meaning to $P(X>20)$ in order to apply the possibility principle. This can be done by "randomizing" $(a,b);$ i.e., we consider a random pair of numbers $(A,B)$ and nonrandom lists $s$, so the possibility principle gives the following:
$$\begin{align}\forall s\,P(X(A,B,s)>20)>0\\
\implies\forall s\,\exists (a,b): X(a,b,s)>20\end{align}$$
which is just the form needed for solution (*).

**NB**: It would not be appropriate randomize $s$, i.e. to consider a random sample $S$, not only because the people are not choosing randomly, but also because in that case the possibility principle would only give, for specified $(a,b)$,
$$\begin{align}P(X(a,b,S)>20)>0\\
\implies\exists s: X(a,b,s)>20\end{align}$$
which is not the form needed for solution (*).

Now, we need to assign a distribution to $(A,B)$ for which we can in fact show
$$\begin{align}&\forall s\,P(X(A,B,s)>20)>0\end{align}.$$
By letting $(A,B)$ be a pair of numbers chosen at random (without replacement) from $\{1,\ldots,11\},$ the resulting hypergeometric distribution allows an easy calculation using indicator functions and the linearity of expectation. Thus, defining the indicator functions $$I(a,b,s_i)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if both $a$ and $b$ occur in set $s_i$}\\
0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
for any list $s=[s_1,\ldots,s_{111}],$ we have
$$X(a,b,s)=\sum_{i=1}^{111} I(a,b,s_i)$$
hence
$$\begin{align}E\,X(A,B,s)
&=E\,\sum_{i=1}^{111} I(A,B,s_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{111} E\,I(A,B,s_i)\\
&=111\,E\,I(A,B,s_1)\\
&=111\,P(\text{Both $A$ and $B$ occur in $s_1$})\\
&=111\,{\binom{5}{2}\binom{11-5}{0} \over \binom{11}{2}}\quad\text{(hypergeometric)}\\
&=111\,{2\over 11}\\
&=20.1\ldots
\end{align}$$
Thus we have shown that $\forall s\,EX(A,B,s)>20$, and hence that $\forall s\,P(X(A,B,s)>20)>0$; consequently, $\forall s\,\exists(a,b): X(a,b,s)>20$, as required.

---

Generalization:

If $n$ people each name $k$ favorites from a list of $m$ movies, then there are $2$ movies such that at least $p$ people name both of these movies as favorites, where $$p = \left\lceil n{k(k-1)\over m(m-1)}\right\rceil.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still unsure why my application of the possibility principle is incorrect. I calculated the probability of two specific movies being chosen by at least 21 people in a particular sample, which the possibility principle refers to as the probability of a randomly chosen object in the sample having a certain property.

Comment: @Andy The trouble with that approach is that the problem doesn't involve a random sample (i.e. the people don't choose randomly); so, if we specify two movies $a$ and $b$, there's nothing probabilistic to give meaning to $P(X(a,b,s)\ge 21)$, where $X(a,b,s)$ is the number of people who choose both $a$ and $b$ in a specific sample $s$. $X(a,b,s)$ is just some specific number.

Comment: @Andy (cont'd) If you nevertheless assume a *random* sample, say $S$, then the possibility principle only gives $\left(P(X(a,b,S)\ge 21)>0\implies \text{there exists a sample $s$ such that $X(a,b,s)\ge 21$}\right)$, whereas we need a result that holds for *all* samples. This is in contrast to letting $A$ and $B$ be random, and showing (as in my answer) that $P(X(A,B,s)\ge 21)>0$ *for all possible samples $s$*, so by the p.p., for all $s$ there exist $(a,b)$ such that $X(a,b,s)\ge 21.$

Comment: @Andy I've added more detail to my answer, addressing this issue.

Comment: Ok that makes it clearer that the possibility principle the way I used it simply shows that P(A) > 0 where A is the event that 2 movies are selected by at least 21 people but not that this is true for a specific list s=[s1,…,s111]. Thanks for the clarification.